# Can't start a Unity session from an upgraded account but I can from a new one

Tags: unity, 11.10, upgrade, login-screen

After upgrading to 11.10 I can't seem to login into an X session in no matter what mode I try (Unity, Unity 2D, Recovery Console, Gnome, and Classic Gnone). I was able though to start a unity session from a newly created account.

I see nothing obvious in /var/log/syslog /var/log/Xorg.0.log /var/log/lightdm/* and ~/.xsession-error.

I tried also removing all the gnome, and unity configuration directories/files from the upgraded account hoping that it would reinitialize the environment, but it did not.

Any suggestions please on how I may use/reset/reinitialize/reconfigure unity from my upgraded account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try ctrl-alt-F1 then login with your regular account. Then

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.old
```

according to this bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/871667

Comment: Yes! that did it!